# What is the different between useImperativeHandle and useRef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

As I understand, `useImperativeHandle` helps parent component able to call function of its children component. You can see a simple example below

```
const Parent = () => {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const onClick = () => ref.current.focus();

    return <>
        <button onClick={onClick} />
        <FancyInput ref={ref} />
    </>
}

function FancyInput(props, ref) {
    const inputRef = useRef();
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      focus: () => {
        inputRef.current.focus();
      }
    }));
    return <input ref={inputRef} />;
}

FancyInput = forwardRef(FancyInput);
```

but it can be easy achieved by using only `useRef`

```
const Parent = () => {
    const ref = useRef({});
    const onClick = () => ref.current.focus();

    return <>
        <button onClick={onClick} />
        <FancyInput ref={ref} />
    </>
}

function FancyInput(props, ref) {
    const inputRef = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current.focus = inputRef.current.focus
    }, [])
    return <input ref={inputRef} />;
}

FancyInput = forwardRef(FancyInput);
```

So what is the true goal of `useImperativeHandle`. Can someone give me some advices?. Thank you

Comment: I think your `ref` should have `{}` as initial value instead of `null` (2nd example), isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something similar to the relationship between `useMemo` and `useCallback` where `useCallback(fn, deps)` is equivalent to `useMemo(() => fn, deps)`. Sometimes there is more than one way to accomplish a goal.

I'd say in the case of `useImperativeHandle` the code can be a bit more succinct/**DRY** when you need to expose out more than an single property.

Examples:

```
function FancyInput(props, ref) {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focus: () => inputRef.current.focus(),
    property,
    anotherProperty,
    ... etc ...
  }), []); // use appropriate dependencies

  ...
}
```

vs

```
function FancyInput(props, ref) {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.focus = inputRef.current.focus;
    ref.current.property = property;
    ref.current.anotherProperty = anotherProperty;
    ... etc ...
  }, []); // use appropriate dependencies

  ...
}
```

Not a big difference, but the `useImperativeHandle` is less code.

Comment: small comment: `useImperativeHandle` also has a dependency array, so you'd have to remove `[]` from `useEffect` for them to be similar (unless there are no other differences)

Answer (score 2):

> it can be easy achieved by using only `useRef`

No, you need at least another `useEffect` or probably better `useLayoutEffect`?
And even then it does a teeny tiny bit more than your code.

```
useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
  focus: () => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }
}));
```

is more likely equivalent to:

```
// using a function.
// no need to create this object over and over if there is no `ref`, 
// or no need to update the `ref`.
const createRef = () => ({
  focus: () => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }
});

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  // refs can be functions!
  if (typeof ref === "function") {
    ref(createRef());

    // when the ref changes, the old one is updated to `null`. 
    // Same on unmount.
    return () => {
      ref(null);
    }
  }

  // and the same thing again for ref-objects
  if (typeof ref === "object" && ref !== null && "current" in ref) {
    ref.current = createRef();

    return () => {
      ref.current = null;
    }
  }
}, [ref]);
```